# Is it possible to build one apk for 3 architectures?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is it possible to build one apk for 3 architectures?

I am not talking about `appBundle`. Is there any way to build one apk for 3 architectues?

**The app should be running any devices**

```
arm64-v8a-release.apk
armeabi-v7a-release.apk
x86_64-release.apk
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just run `flutter build apk`

**Note**

Run `flutter build apk --split-per-abi`
(The flutter build command defaults to --release.)

This command results in three APK files:

```
<app dir>/build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-armeabi-v7a-release.apk
<app dir>/build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-arm64-v8a-release.apk
<app dir>/build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-x86_64-release.apk
```

Removing the `--split-per-abi` flag results in a fat APK that contains your code compiled for all the target ABIs. Such APKs are larger in size than their split counterparts, causing the user to download native binaries that are not applicable to their device’s architecture.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by specifing ABIs, which you can configue in the `android/app/build.gradle` file, for example:

```
release {
  ndk {
    abiFilters 'arm64-v8a', 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86_64'
  }
}
```

The default behavior of the build system is to include the binaries for each ABI in a single APK, also known as a fat APK.

You can learn more on ABIs [HERE](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis).